# Is there any API from Bing like Google Places?

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, bing, bing-api

Anyone knows whether Bing provides any API similar to Google Places?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use Bing API with Phonebook source type to retieve information about businesses:

- general information about the Phonebook source type API is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251005.aspx)
- JSON-based implementation example available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd250913.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The [Bing Services Location API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701715.aspx) might be what you are looking for.